# How do I indicate feature interaction in Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to playing around with Azure ML, having used R a little bit for machine learning previously.

In R, you can define [interactions](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/interaction.html) between variables using a multiplication operator, such as

```
lm(formula = target ~ var1 * var2 + var3)
```

Which would indicate that `var1` and `var2` interact while `var3` is independent.

However, I haven’t found any way to indicate this in Azure ML.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In AzureML Studio, there's 2 options:

- Use Execute Python Script or Execute R Script to manually create such variables. Note that this approach has the downside of increasing the size of your dataset.
- Use [Train Vowpal Wabbit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/train-vowpal-wabbit-version-8-model) module, with feature interactions turned on (--interactive), see [Example Manipulation options](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments). Vowpal Wabbit can create such features on-line during training, which can be more efficient.